# How does Zabbix use the value of a monitor item in a macro

Tags: zabbix

I want to use the value from the monitor item in a custom macro. Is this possible now? Zabbix version 4.0.11

Comment: You can't use it as a macro, but you can use it in a Calculated Item.

Comment: Is there a way to use it outside of the monitor item value？

Comment: for doing what?

Comment: Our monitor item gets the token of the Web page and wants to use it in the Web interface

Comment: that's and End to End check, I wouldn't use Zabbix for that. Try using `{macro}=regex:<regular expression>` see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_monitoring